# Couldn't execute hive current_user function from spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql

I am trying to execute hive SQL from spark. The following works fine using spark-sql or from spark-submit for python with embedded hive sql statements.

```
spark-sql --master yarn -e "select count(*) from adhoc.dual;"
```

But I can't execute 
    spark-sql --master yarn -e "select current_user() from adhoc.dual;"

I get the following error

```
Error in query: Undefined function: 'current_user'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7
```

current_user is a hive permanent function.

Similarly from pyspark, I can execute most of hive statements including the ones involving user defined UDF after register the UDF as temporary function like:
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION foo AS 'com.example.foo';

But execution of hive's create macro results in failure

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark Hive example").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO PacificTzDate(ts BIGINT) DATE(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'America/Los_Angeles')")
```

This fails with the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nOperation not allowed: CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nCREATE TEMPORARY MACRO PacificTzDate(ts BIGINT) DATE(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'America/Los_Angeles')\n^^^\n"
```

19/01/02 20:09:49 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Comment: Could you try replacing with

`hive -e "select col, 'whoami' from table1;` or

`logged_in_user()`

Comment: Did you mean running the SQL from hive?
hive2_3 --version
Hive 2.3.4-SNAPSHOT


hive2_3 -e "select current_user()"

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/mnt/apache-hive-2.3.4-SNAPSHOT-bin/conf/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
OK
_c0
XYZ
Time taken: 0.608 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive2_3 -e "select logged_in_user()"

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/mnt/apache-hive-2.3.4-SNAPSHOT-bin/conf/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
OK
_c0
NULL
Time taken: 0.486 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)